# How to generate the proxy in .net application by consuming java web services?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I am developing smart device application. In that I am consuming the java web services in .net window application ( C# ). The java web services resides on the another machine. I am able to add the web reference in .net application. It is showing the list of web methods. But I am not getting the proxy class in my .net application. I am not able to call the web methods defined in the java web services in my .net application. What should I do to call the web methods from java web serives in .net? Is there any setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your project and from the menu click Project > Show All files, then you should see the generated proxy class named as Reference.cs.

Alternatively AFAIK you can use [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) to generate the proxy from the command line.